# Importing texture with script based on the name of the material

Tags: texturing, materials, scripting, import, file-browser

I want to automate this through script:

1. Open Shader Editor
2. Select BSDF Node
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Open "textures" file
5. Select multiple image textures that consist of the material name + shader type name
6. Enter

Is this possible? I barely know anything about coding and I've only tried automating renaming objects and material through text editor.

Comment: yes it is. It's too much for me to just whip up right now, but a good starting point is to got to the scripting tab and check the bottom left. Everytime you do something in Blender, the python command to that action will be shown. Once you piece this together, you can ask a more specific answer and increase your chances of a good answer.

Comment: I made a script that does that here, so yes it is possible. https://github.com/thelabcat/SMD-Model-PostImport/blob/main/SMD_material_setup.py

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.